# Empty /var folder on FTP client even though there are files in there

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

I recently created a VPS server with OVH (running CentOS 7). I have installed the basic LAMP stack (without the L), as well as SSH and FTP, on a fresh install of the VPS. The FTP is what I am having trouble with. The first time I tried this, I could connect using FileZilla and browse to the /var/www/html folder and upload my files. After mucking some stuff up and reinstalling the OS + Programs as above, FileZilla is being strange. The /var folder appears completely empty, which is strange considering:

- There are files in that folder
- It's not a network issue (Clean reinstall - Worked fine before - and...)
- This is the only folder appearing empty

[This](http://pastebin.com/FzSaMsvT) is a log I kept of all the commands I entered into the server to show I haven't mucked anything up by just fiddling with permissions and stuff. Also, I don't think it's an error with permissions, because it worked fine before when I hadn't even touched any perms, and I am logged into FTP with the root user (I know, bad, but just for testing), there are no other users on the server etc.

Sorry for the large amount of detail, but I wanted to provide as much info as possible. This has been bugging me all day :>

```
$ ls -ld /var
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Aug 27 20:06 /var

$ ls -la /var | head
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Aug 27 20:06 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 Aug 27 18:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Jun 10  2014 adm
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root   53 Aug 27 19:34 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 May 12 22:18 crash
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   32 Mar 31 14:24 db
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   17 Mar 31 14:24 empty
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   16 Aug 27 18:45 ftp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Jun 10  2014 games

$ getfacl /var
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

$ ls -Z /var
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       adm
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       cache
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:kdump_crash_t:s0 crash
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       db
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       empty
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 ftp
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:games_data_t:s0 games
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       gopher
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       kerberos
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0   lib
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       local
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:var_lock_t:s0  lock -> ../run/lock
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:mail_spool_t:s0 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       nis
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       opt
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       preserve
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0   run -> ../run
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_spool_t:s0 spool
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       tmp
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       var
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 www
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_yp_t:s0    yp

$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

[Config](http://pastebin.com/6GkuuPmv)

Comment: Your pastebin post was removed. Also, please provide the output of `ls -ld /var` and `ls -la /var | head` and  `getfacl /var` and `ls -Z /var` and `sestatus`.  You can edit your question to add the the output of those commands.

Comment: Fixed link, added the outputs from those commands.

Comment: One more thing, the contents (at least the changes you made) of `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

Comment: Done, the only real things I added are in my command log

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel mixed emotions right now. After uninstalling vsftpd and installing proftpd, then uninstalling that and mucking around with a whole bunch of stuff before finally reinstalling vsftpd, I finally... Was still a getting an error. But it was a different error: everything was blank. No files. Nothing. I was very confused until I tried connecting with port 22 rather than port 21, and that somehow seemed to work! I swear to whatever God is up there that I will never touch another FTP setting again in my lifetime for fear of something breaking again XD